# Nested query update in a loop in mongodb

Tags: mongodb

I have collection the structure of which is :-

```js
Subscribed.insert({
    "name":  "Manager1",
    "emailId": "arora.priya4172@gmail.com",
    "category": "Finance",
    "designation": 'Head',
    "done": false,
    "categorySubscribedUsers": [
        {
            "_id": "u4._id",
            "username": "u4.profile.name",
            "issuesNotToDisplay": []
        },
        {
            "_id": "u4._id",
            "username": "u4.profile.name",
            "issuesNotToDisplay": []
        },
        {
            "_id": "u4._id",
            "username": "u4.profile.name",
            "issuesNotToDisplay": []
        }
    ]
});
```

I want to add the value in issuesNotToDisplay field. The query which I am using to update the issuesNotToDisplay field is as follows:-

```js
Subscribed.update(
    {
         "_id":Subscribed.findOne({
             "category": "Finance",
             "categorySubscribedUsers.username" :"abhi"
         })._id
    },
    { "$addToSet": {
        "categorySubscribedUsers.0.issueNotToDisplay": "25PEgZoMamLSTDdw7"
    }}
)
```

This one I used in the console (browser and mongo) and it is working fine but when I replace the numerical value with the loop index (j here). It is not working why so? and what should be done to make it work.

The query with j index is as follows:-

```js
Subscribed.update(
    {
        "_id":Subscribed.findOne({
            "category": "Finance", 
            "categorySubscribedUsers.username" :"abhi"
        })._id
    },{ 
        "$addToSet": {
            "categorySubscribedUsers.j.issueNotToDisplay": "25PEgZoMamLSTDdw7"
        }
    }
)
```

Please anyone let me know how we can update the collection field inside a loop in mongodb.

Comment: I think your variable `j` is processed as a part of the field name, not as a variable.

Comment: Ya, I also thought about this and I also tried it without "" but still not working. Is not there any provision in mongodb to update any collection in a loop???

Answer (score 0):

```
Subscribed.update({
    "category": "Finance",
    "categorySubscribedUsers.username" : "u4.profile.name"
},
{
    "$set":{
        "categorySubscribedUsers.$.issueNotToDisplay": "25PEgZoMamLSTDdw7"
    }
});
```